# print out a group of numbers in hex / little endian format

Tags: c, formatting, hex, endianness

Wrote a small program to print out some numbers in hex so that I can simply copy and paste them into a hex editor instead of typing them one by one. I have them printing out properly except I need them to be in little endian format. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
  int ii;
  for (ii = 3; ii<413; ii++)
  {
    printf("%.4x ", ii);
  }
}
```

Right now my output looks like the following:

```
0043 0044 0045 0046 0047 0048 0049 004a 004b 004c
```

but I want it to look like

```
4300 4400 4500 4600 ...
```

Comment: `printf("%.2x%.2x ", (ii & 0xff), (ii & 0xff00) >> 8);`? Of course need to be aware that this only handles 16 bit values.

Comment: To avoid sign extension effects, use `printf("%.4hhx ", ii);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by printing each byte at a time, like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned a;
    for(a=0x43; a<=0x4c; a++)                   // as your question
        printf("%04x ", a);
    printf("\n");

    for(a=0x43; a<=0x4c; a++)
        printf("%02x%02x ", a & 255, (a / 256) & 255);  // endian reversed
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
0043 0044 0045 0046 0047 0048 0049 004a 004b 004c
4300 4400 4500 4600 4700 4800 4900 4a00 4b00 4c00
```